# Deploy QT Quick Desktop Application on Windows

Tags: deployment, desktop, qml

I have wrote an amazing QML and C++ Desktop Application using QT Quick Desktop Components on Windows 7 OS, and now I have to deploy it, I want it to work on any other machine - with or with no QT installed on it, but I don't know how to do it, I had never deployed QT Application, and all the more - QT Quick application using plugins.

Any clear way to do it?

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/deployment-windows.html)'s a simple guide, right out of the Qt documentation site.

Also it's the first result for googling "Qt deploy windows".

Comment: Thanks for the reference, it was helpful.